# Convergence of sums of $\sin(kY)$ where Y is uniform

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. Let $X_k=\sin(kY)$.

I want to show that $\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}\to 0$ almost surely.

I thought of using the strong law of large numbers but it requires the $X_k$'s to be identically distributed.

Comment: Your idea to use a law of large numbers is fine.

Comment: @Math-fun Can you elaborate? The summands are just not i.i.d., they are not independent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compute the geometric sum  $e^{iy}+e^{2iy}+..._+e^{iny}$ and show that $\frac 1 n (e^{iy}+e^{2iy}+..._+e^{iny}) \to 0$ for all real $y$ such that $e^{iy} \neq 1$. Take the imaginary part.  Can you finish?